# Pass GET parameters to jsfiddle embedded version

Tags: javascript, parameters, jsfiddle

I am using in my website the embedded version of a jsfiddle like so:

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/mebibou/va5pu0bd/embed/"></script>
```

I tried to pass parameters in that url like `?foo=bar` but I get an error in the console from the script on that url:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at createEmbedFrame (?foor=bar:19)
createEmbedFrame @ ?foor=bar:19
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ ?foor=bar:43
(anonymous) @ ?foor=bar:45
```

(you can see the code that is executed here: http://jsfiddle.net/mebibou/va5pu0bd/embed/?foo=bar)
I also tried to use the iframe version of the embed but it loads another `iFrame` within that removes the url parameter I put. Is it at all possible? what I want to do is pass parameters from my website to the jsfiddle code, and thought url params would be the easiest way

Comment: I suppose you haven't shared the error message because you think it isn't related to the issue, but if it's triggered in the exact moment that you load the fiddle then there might be a relation after all. Can you please edit the question and include it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes I was thinking its not that relevant since it is how jsfiddle embeds their code, but I've edited with a simple live example to make it more complete, thanks

Comment: Thank you. That's enough to reproduce the issue. I get is `TypeError: target is null` at `target.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, target.nextSibling)`., what is essentially the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error goes away if you remove the trailing slash from the path component:

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/mebibou/va5pu0bd/embed/?foo=bar"></script>
                                                        ^
```

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/mebibou/va5pu0bd/embed?foo=bar"></script>
```

The error happens because the `jsfiddle.net` server strips such slash when composing the `uriOriginal` variable:

```
var uriOriginal           = "http://jsfiddle.net/mebibou/va5pu0bd/embed?foo=bar"
```

That leads to a CSS selector that doesn't match your `<script>` tag:

```js
var uriOriginal           = "http://jsfiddle.net/mebibou/va5pu0bd/embed?foo=bar"
var uriOriginalNoProtocol = uriOriginal.split("//").pop()
var target                = document.querySelector("script[src*='" + uriOriginalNoProtocol + "']")
console.log("script[src*='" + uriOriginalNoProtocol + "']", target);
```

However, if your `<script>` tags omits the slash then the selector does match.

It's worth nothing though that this hack merely prevents the error and allows the fiddle to load and run. It doesn't transmit the original URL parameters to the final iframe because its path is already hard-coded in the JavaScript code generated by the server:

```
var uriEmbedded = "http://jsfiddle.net/va5pu0bd/embedded/?username=mebibou")
iframe.src               = uriEmbedded
target.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, target.nextSibling)
```

To sum up, passing URL parameters is probably an unsupported scenario.

Comment: does not work, doing this will add an iframe with `src="http://jsfiddle.net/va5pu0bd/embedded/?username=mebibou"` so the `foo=bar` parameter is removed

Comment: @Guillaume Correct, I didn't go as far. This just makes the fiddle load. The iframe is hard-coded (`var uriEmbedded           = "http://jsfiddle.net/va5pu0bd/embedded/?username=mebibou"`).